# How can I handly normalize string that contains special characters like &apos, &agrave, &ograve, etc?

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, escaping, character

In a Java application I have the following situation:

I have some valorized **String** field (the data are taken from an XML) that can contains:

- Phrases containing apostrophe character, so in these strings I have the **&apos** character.
- Words containing accented letters, so in these setrins I have something like **&agrave** or **&ograve**, etcetc

The problem is that I have to normalize these strings changing these special character into the standard character.

For example, if it find **&apos** character this have to be replaced by the **'** character. If into a string there is **&agrave** it have to be replaced by **à** character.

How can I do this operation in a smart way? Exist some library or something like this that do it for me?

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can also use  [Spring's HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(String input) method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/HtmlUtils.html)